# Converting into jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I need help in converting this code in a jquery plugin

```
$({left: 20}).animate({left: 0}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing:'linear',
  step: function() {
    $('#pp').text(this.left);
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('#pp').text(this.left);
  }
});
```

I want that the values ‘20’, ‘0’, ‘1000’ and ‘#pp’ must be passed to this plugin. How can I do it?

Comment: [Start here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link to creating a jQuery plugin:

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

how about this:

```
;(function ($) {

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {    

        // define defaults
        var defaults = {
            left1: 20,
            left2: 0,
            duration: 1000
        };

        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);    

        this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            $({left: o.left1}).animate({left: o.left2}, {
                  duration: o.duration,
                  easing:'linear',
                  step: function() {
                    $this.text(this.left);
                  },
                  complete: function() {
                    $this.text(this.left);
                  }
            });

        });

        return this;
     }

 })(jQuery);
 // end
```

and usage is like this:

```
$('#pp').myPlugin({
      left1: 20,
      left2: 0,
      duration: 1000
});
```